# Sending BlackMagic DeckLink Studio 4K over RTMP streams with FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtmp

I'm trying to send a stream of video that's coming into a BlackMagic DeckLink Studio 4K capture card over a few different RTMP streams at once with FFmpeg. The command that I am doing it with is this:

`ffmpeg -re -format_code Hi59 -f decklink -i 'DeckLink Studio 4K' -map 0 -flags +global_header -vcodec libx264 -crf 25 -preset medium -pix_fmt yuv422p -acodec aac -f tee "[f=flv]rtmp://ip1/live/test|[f=flv]rtmp://ip2/live/test`.

However, whenever I send this video out, I just get color bars when looking at the stream. I tried using a different video source (the testsrc supplied by FFmpeg), and that sends out fine over RTMP to multiple stream destinations.

Is there something weird with how tee and the decklink stuff work in FFmpeg? Or is there an issue with my command?

Answer (score 0):

If you see colors bars, that means that ffmpeg is connecting to the card and streaming fine but the card is giving the bars. Your command says that ffmpeg is expecting 1920X1080@29.97 interlaced, make sure that is the format into the Decklink. You can also try explicitly setting the connection type, example:

```
ffmpeg -re -format_code Hi59 -video_input sdi -f decklink -i 'DeckLink Studio 4K' -map 0 -flags +global_header -vcodec libx264 -crf 25 -preset medium -pix_fmt yuv422p -acodec aac -f tee "[f=flv]rtmp://ip1/live/test|[f=flv]rtmp://ip2/live/test
```

If you are still running into issues, make sure that the BlackMagic software can see the video signal, and it's the format you expect.

One last thing to check, if its an HDMI input make sure it is not HDCP; it's not supported.

Comment: So, I can definitely see the signal, since if I only send the output to one destination, then the video works perfectly fine. I haven't tried setting the video_input source directly, so I will definitely try that. Thanks for the response!

Comment: I tried adding -video_input sdi but I'm still getting the same issue sadly. The data is coming in from an SDI cable. I think you're right, something is wrong with the format of the output from the Decklink going into FFmpeg. We should be allowing at 59.94, but for whatever reason, I can only stream (when doing a single stream) using 29.97. I will look more into it, thanks.